# No wireless firmware found from a Wi-PI on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wireless, software-installation, firmware, wireless-adapter

My boss wanted me to install Raspbian through raspbian ua net install, instead of through NOOBs. It just got done installed a base-level Raspbain from sources files and its LXDE gui.

However, I have a Wi-Pi adapter plugged in and there is no wireless connection. The Gui says that "device is not ready (firmware missing)".

Also I tried to run lspci and it came back with

```
 pcilub: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
 lspci: Cannot find any working access method
```

Comment: There is no PCI bus on the pi.  Those are *USB* jacks.  Try `lsusb` (you may need to install `usbutils`).

Answer (score 1):

**Before** continuing with this answer, type the command `lsusb` and make sure the adapter is listed.

---

Sometimes the RPi does not recognize Wi-fi adapters in the GUI, but this doesn't mean you cannot use them. You will just have to edit system files manually instead.

So, first edit your `wpa_supplicant` file be entering the command

`sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

then, add this to the bottom:

```
network={
    ssid="NETWORK"
    psk="PASS"
}
```

Obviously, you need to replace `"NETWORK"` your your network name and `"PASS"` with your network's password.

Finally, edit your `interfaces` file by typing the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And, **if this isn't already there**, add this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

---

Reboot the Pi and it should connect to your network.